# Implement a Color Picker for Android Clock Widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have spent almost 10 days searching for a tutorial or any help describing how to add a colour picker to my Clock Widget.

My widget is a simple clock with 7 colours, but I want to make it completely usable free. "the user chooses what colour he/she like", "the clock, **NOT** the background" of that clock.

Could you please direct me and help me to find the way to make it like that?

I tried to use the setBackgroundResources to change the actual background to the the frame of the clock "clock_dial", and tried to make the background a BLANK image to avoid the colour effect on the image. But I almost gave up guys.
Help is appreciated.

```
views.setInt(R.id.widget_aclock, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.whand_dial);

                views.setInt(R.id.widget_aclock, "setBackgroundColor", color);
```

Comment: **One:** With no details beyond _My widget is a simple clock with 7 colors, but I want to make it completely usable free. "the user chooses what color he/she like", "the clock, NOT the background"._, you add no further details to the post. Without that, any objective help is effectively rendered, difficult. **And Two:** See if this [library here](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker) is of use.

Comment: thank you silverback for your care, but what details I have to provide, I'm ready to

Comment: First, loose the **sarcasm** when replying (_thank you silverback for your care_). Second, what Clock widget? Post the code. What have you tried to enable the change of color (I assume in Java). Post that code too. Without any of that data offered by you, there is a possibility of we having to speculate the nature of a solution that would work for you.

Comment: have a look  at this sample http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/

Comment: have a look at this one . https://github.com/brk3/android-color-picker

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-home-screen-app-widget-with-onclick-event/ 
it is a perfect for me, BUT I could't change "I didn't know" how to make it change the clock color it self, NOT the background of that clock.

Comment: HELP PLEASE .. @IceMAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker may be what you are looking for, but with such a vague description I am not sure.